# ContourPlot yields discontinuous line segments

Tags: plotting

I want to make plots of unit spheres in different normed spaces for the class that I teach. However I've ran into a problem for the max-norm. The code

```
ContourPlot[Max[Abs[x], Abs[y]] == 1, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, 
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}]]
```

gives

[image: where the corners at]

As you can see, the corners are cut off...

What can I do about that?

Comment: What version are you using? With `13.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)`, I get this: [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/P2XHhoH.png)

Comment: Interesting... I got `13.2.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)`

Comment: I don't see gaps on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Comment: Try: `Exclusions->None`

Comment: @DanielHuber This does the trick! Thank you!